# The only() method - Mongoengine

Tags: mongoengine

Small Mongoengine question: 
I wanted to ask if there is any use in doing this:

```
MyClass.objects.only('MyEmbeddedField.MyField').first().MyEmbeddedField.MyField
```

in order to save complexity ?

From what I understand, calling the first() method downloads the entire object from the DB (correct me if I am wrong). Is this even a good idea?

How do I **solely** access a specific field from the document ?

Answer (score 4):

Here is something I have tried to replicate your use case. As per [.only()](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.only), it only loads a subset of the document's total fields.

Consider the following Document.

```
class Test(Document):
    my_first_field = StringField()
    my_second_field = IntField()
```

and then,

```
t = Test(my_first_field='my field data', my_second_field=10)
t.save()
```

Then once you query them,

```
for i in Test.objects(id=t.id).only('my_first_field').exclude('id'):
    print(i.to_json())

for i in Test.objects(id=t.id).only('my_first_field'):
    print(i.to_json())
```

Like so, you get the preferred output:

```
{"my_first_field": "my field data"}
{"_id": {"$oid": "5aafc55119185b2ac0f8e729"}, "my_first_field": "my field data"}
```

Similarly, you can chain the `.first()` to the query as well and would fetch you the first matched query with the fields you ask for to include and/or exclude.

```
Test.objects(id=t.id).only('my_first_field').exclude('id').first().to_json()
```

Comment: Note that if you exclude a field that has a default value it will return the default value... docs: http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#retrieving-a-subset-of-fields   open issue: https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/2030

Comment: It has been a while, but this does not answer my original question. We are talking about complexity considerations, not a breakdown of what each operation does